# problema con tildes al listar archivos con cmd

Tags: cmd, batch

estoy intentando listar los archivos de un directorio en un fichero de texto para luego imprimir dicha lista. Utilizo la instrucción `dir /s /b >info.txt` y lo hace pero tengo algunos archivos con nombres con tildes y no soy capaz de resolver el asunto. 
Estoy en un windows10.
¿Alguien que sepa?

Gracias.

Answer (score 1):

puedes cambiar la página de códigos activa de la consola con el comando
`chcp`. Te dejo un ejemplo de uso del mismo y un enlace con la descripción del comando

```
chcp 850
```

Y el enlace [chcp](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/chcp#BKMK_examples)

Answer (score 0):

Solución para mostrar correctamente tildes o "ñ" en una consola CMD.
1- Desde la consola CMD, cambiar la página de códigos activa con el comando CHCP 850 (Multilenguaje)
2- Asegurarse de salvar el archivo .bath o .java (etc) con un formato de Encoding = ANSI. Desde el NOTEPAD de Windows esta opción se muestra en "Save as" junto al botón "Save" en una lista desplegable.